# How to pass HttpServletRequest JSON inbound data from controller to service method

Tags: grails, service, controller, dataflow

I understand the general dictum to isolate business logic to service methods in Grails. All my previous Grails web services, have no inbound JSON, XML etc. Currently, I am required to take JSON payload, which contains {finish_time: 2020-05-12T18:19:00Z, start_time: 2020-05-14T18:19:00Z}, to use in my SQL. Running Grails 2.5.6. Unfortunately, I have no idea how service methods, can access the inbound JSON payload data. This has to be common, but I am not understanding data pass/access from controller to service methods. I’m not versed in Grails well enough to waste ya’lls time showing what I’ve tried. I have not found any examples/explanations of service methods working on inbound https posted JSON/XML data from the controller. Thank You in advance, as to me this  seems like a very fundamental task.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pass the json data as an argument to a service method that handles this operation

Controller action

```
def actionName() {
    def json = '{"finish_time": "2020-05-12T18:19:00Z", "start_time": "2020-05-14T18:19:00Z"}'
    serviceInstance.methodName(json)
}
```

Service method

```
def methodName(json) {
    def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def data = jsonSlurper.parseText(json) // here data is a Groovy data structures in this case a Map

    // ... sql logic
}
```

Comment: Excellent - Thank You Mario and as well Thank Jeff. Both of you helped. Since this is my first question, I am not sure how to pick whom should be selected as the Answer. Please advise and know I am thankful to both!

Comment: Thats good, someone marked my answer as not useful, and I understand it has served you, I would appreciate it if you correct that

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, I have no idea how service methods, can access the
>   inbound JSON payload data. This has to be common, but I am not
>   understanding data pass/access from controller to service methods.

There are a number of ways to get access to the JSON payload data in a service but there aren't really many good reasons to want to do that.  Generally folks will do that sort of thing at the controller level.  You mentioned "...the general dictum to isolate business logic to service methods in Grails" but this isn't business logic.  Dealing with web layer details like the body of the request is a perfectly reasonable thing to do in a Grails controller.

You could have a controller like this...

```
class SomeController {

    SomeService someService

    def someAction(Widget w) {
        someService.doSomething w
    }
}
```

With that, if you POST JSON to `someAction`, all of the JSON reading will be done for you and the `Widget` will be initialized with the contents of the JSON.

I hope that helps.

**EDIT**

> I need to see how to set up the Service too.

```
// grails-app/services/demo/SomeService.groovy
package demo

class SomeService {
    void doSomething(Widget w) {
        // Do whatever you need to do with 
        // the information in the Widget...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Well, I am not understanding your response. I need to see how to set up the Service too. Previously, I too get the handling of the JSON payload is acceptable, even recommended. I have tried copying the json to a Map and then try to use the jasonmap payload handler Service.someMethod(Map jsonmap) to work with the data, but for the life of me I cant get it. In your kind example how would the service look please? Very appreciative!

Comment: Thank You so much for your help Jeff. So this is where I ended up in all of my searching, no concrete example of how it should be done. This boggles my mind, as I would assume, there would be many cases of restful API's written in Grails where a JSON payload is received at the controller somehow passing the JSON payload to a service to in turn be processed. What am I missing and how to implement this with best practice?